# Setting an object value to another value in the same object

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to set one value in an object to another, like so:

```
var obj = {  
    value1: 'test'
    value2: value1
}
```

Of course that doesn't work.
I feel like there would be an easier way than extending the object. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var obj = {  
            value1: 'test'
          };

obj.value2 = obj.value1;
```

Comment: I think this is correct way to 'easier way than extending the object' what op wants.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you were missing value2 in the obj :)

Comment: @Pavlo Yes, of course. but once the program's flow crosses the second line, the `obj` would contain a key called `value2`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
var value = 'test';

var obj = {
    value1: value,
    value2: value
}
```

Be aware that because they point to String values, once value1 is changed, value2 will keep the old string instead of changing with value1.